# Problem with Div layouts having semitransparent backgrounds

Tags: html, css, transparency

I have the following layout: nested DIVs, the outer having 100% width and the inner having some fixed width. The inner one is centered using `margin:auto`.

Now I need to set different backgrounds to the DIVs. Say, the inner should be red and the remaining part of the outer should be green. The problem is that the backgrounds need to be **semitransparent** (using PNG or CSS3's `rgba()`). So, the background of the inner DIV does not look red, it becomes brown! Here is my code:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#outer{width:100%;height:50px;background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5)}
#inner{width:800px;height:50px;margin:auto;background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5)}
```

I've tried to use 3 *floated* DIVs inside the `#outer`. But I can't set width for the other 2 DIVs to make the `#inner` to be in the center of the screen. `width:auto` doesn't work as well.

I know such layout is possible with tables; more precisely with elements that have `display:table-cell`. So when I add another "outer" DIV, I get the result I need (3 "levels" are required for table-like layout: *table*, *row*, *cell*). CSS:

```
#outer2{display:table;width:100%}
#outer{height:50px;display:table-row}
#inner{width:800px;height:50px;background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5)}
#left, #right, #inner{display:table-cell}
#left, #right {background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5)}
```

and the ugly HTML:

```
<div id="outer2">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="inner"></div>
        <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any other way to put 3 DIVs in a row with such "balance"? Or, maybe, there is a completely different way to solve the original issue? I mean, the problem appeared only because of the transparency! :)

I don't like the solution with `display:table`, because I've added 3 additional DIVs... Also, please don't suggest any solutions using JS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're feeling edgy and don't mind losing a horizontal scrollbar...

**HTML**

```
<section></section>
```

**CSS**

```
body { overflow-x:hidden; }
section {
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
section:before, section:after {
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    content:"";
    width:9999px;
    position:absolute;
    background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}
section:after { left: 100%; }
section:before { right: 100%; }
```

**Demo: [http://jsfiddle.net/6STug](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/6STug/)**

*Hat-tip, [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/)*

Comment: thanks very much! Like the solutions where styles are determined only by CSS :) Horizontal scrollbar remains the only issue... One partial solution is wrapping the `<section>` into a new `<div>` with `width:100%` and moving `overflow-x:hidden` to that `<div>`. The `body`'s horizontal scrollbar will be shown when there are other fixed-width elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a single background png image on the #outer? The image could contain the semitransparent red then the semitransparent green and again the semitransparent red.

Comment: thanks for idea! Some issues: 

1. I will need to use PNG with 2000px width, instead of 2 1px PNGs :) 

2. if the inner DIV's width is changed (for example, if it is set by PHP depending on something) PNG should be generated again. 

3. I would like to use `rgba` because the colors are set from CMS (don't want to generate PNGs)

Comment: a 2000px x 1px can be less than 5ko so that's not a problem but for the other point i'm with you ;) - Don't forget the css3 gradient property then.